# MFC: hiding a toolbar button

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm currently disable certain buttons by handling `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` and calling `->Enable( TRUE / FALSE )`.

What would be the best way to completely hide the button instead?

I've tried using `HideButton` and that makes the button image invisible, but it still takes up space so there is a blank area between visible buttons.

Thanks.

Comment: I wont call it hiding if you dont want the button to be there, rather you seem to want to remove the button and add it dynamically after sometime.

Answer (score 3):

If You want to hide the toolbar specific button use this code.

```
m_wndToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().HideButton(ID_TOOLBAR1,TRUE);
```

here m_wndToolBar is a ToolBar Object.
     ID_TOOLBAR1 is a which button you want  to hide that button control.

Comment: I only need to manually edit rc file to hide separator. Other than that, this method works great.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `toolbar.SendMessage(TB_AUTOSIZE);` after the HideButton();

I would recommend to show/hide those buttons elsewhere than OnUpdateCommandUI because these occur too often and may cause flicker. Although not MFC I have a similar code that works:

```
void HideToolbarButton(HWND toolbar, UINT command_id)
{
    TBBUTTONINFO tbinfo;
    tbinfo.cbSize = sizeof(tbinfo);
    tbinfo.dwMask = TBIF_STATE;
    tbinfo.state  = TBSTATE_HIDDEN;
    SendMessage(toolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, command_id, (LPARAM)&tbinfo );
}
```

Comment: toolbar.SendMessage(TB_AUTOSIZE) does not shrink the toolbar after hiding a button :(